# Should find if the string of numbers is a valid pin

Tags: python

For some reason this code prints true for numbers without a length of 4 or 6 and I'm not sure why.

```
def validate_pin(pin):
    try:
        pin = int(pin)
    except ValueError:
        print(False)
        exit()
    if len(str(pin)) == 4 or 6:
        if pin < 0:
            print(False)
            exit()
        elif pin >= 0:
            print(True)
            exit()
    elif len(pin) != 4 or 6:
        print(False)
        exit()
```

Comment: Your conditional statement has issues.

Comment: `or 6` is always true

Comment: Additionally the order of the checks is wrong. If you enter the PIN "0123" it should be valid. But you transform it to an integer and then back to a string and that gives you "123". Suddenly the valid PIN isn't valid anymore.